# multiple ids affected when i only want to change one (javascript & jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of `.box` elements within a `.color_container`. I've written this function so that when I click on one of those boxes, I am able to change its background color. This works fine with one box, but when I click on another and change its color, all other boxes I've clicked on are affected too.

I would only like to change the color of the box that I have just clicked on. Here is my code. Many thanks in advance for any help with this.

```
function defineColor(){
$(".color_container .box").click(function(){
    var boxToModify = $(this);

    if( $(this) .hasClass("plus") ){
        $(this) .css("background-color", "rgb(255, 255, 255)")
                .removeClass("plus")
                .contents().remove();
    };

    var rgb = $(this).css("background-color").match(/\d{1,3}/g);        
    $("#box_r input").val(rgb[0]);
    $("#box_g input").val(rgb[1]);
    $("#box_b input").val(rgb[2]);

    $(".box input").keyup(function(event){

        var value = $(this).val();

        if(value > 255 || isNaN(value) ){
            alert("Error! Input must be a number 255 or less.");
        }else if( value >= 0 && value <=255){
            var r = $("#box_r input").val();
            var g = $("#box_g input").val();
            var b = $("#box_b input").val();
            var output = "rgb(" + r + ", " + g +", " + b + ")";

            $(boxToModify).css("background-color", output);
        };
    });
});
```

};

Comment: Can you post your HTML.  You may have duplicate elements that are matching your selector criteria.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but note that `$(boxToModify)` is unnecessary as `boxToModify` is already a jQuery object (third line of code). So, you can just do `boxToModify.css(...`

Comment: You should not add handlers inside a handler.  Your click handler creates a key up.  That's bad.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to change this:

```
$(".box input").keyup(function(event){
```

to this:

```
$(this).find('input').off('keyup').on('keyup', function(event) {
```

You're binding a keyup event to all boxes with that class on each click of a single box.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that didn't quite do it.

Comment: Are you certain? Without a fiddle or anything, I'm sticking with my answer, heh.

Comment: It looks like when I swap your bit in, the function becomes unable to define `value` or something because it no longer modifies the background color of any of the boxes. I'm kind of new to this (as i'm sure you can tell from my code).

Comment: It should work if the box indeed has an input inside it. If not, then you're making some bold assumptions with class responsibilities.